# How can I Find All Uses of a Google Script Library?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Script library that is used by at least 100 other scripts (some that are bound to spreadsheets/documents, some that are not). How can I find all of these client scripts that reference my library script?

More specifically, I need to be able to add a new feature into the library that requires new permissions that I (the user) must grant. The client scripts won't run if I just add this feature to the library without granting the permissions to each of the client scripts. So ultimately, I need to give this new permission to each of the clients. And if I knew what scripts were actually using this library, I could do that manually for each one. But I need to URL's or ID's or something for each of those scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately this is not possible to do.*

#### More Information

It is possible to get a list of standalone Scripts from your Drive, though scripts bound to a file can not be searched for using regular searching methods.

It is possible, using the help of [this Google Account page](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1) to get a list of all the Apps that have access to your account, though only files you have authorised will appear here, and apps which are not just those created by you in Apps Script will appear there (for example, other add-ons or even Android Apps bound to your account appear here).

#### A Partial Workaround:

Using Google Apps Script, you can list all Apps Script Projects that you own with help of the `MimeType` enumeration `GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT`

```js
 var scripts = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT);
  var arr =[ ];
  while (scripts.hasNext()) {
    var script = scripts.next();
    arr.push(script)
  }
  Logger.log(arr);
```

Or even just searching for `type:script` in Drive, however this only returns a list of scripts that are ***not*** bound to a file.

You can then use regular [Google Drive search terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms) to find which of these files contain, for example, a unique method name that the library uses. I am aware this isn't a perfect solution and you would still have to look for projects bound to a file using the [above webpage](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1).

#### Feature Request:

It appears that back in 2014 a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761966) for this was made on Google's Issue Tracker, though I would suggest creating another feature request for this here as it was marked as a duplicate of another issue. You can make a feature request under the correct Apps Script component [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - Enum `MimeType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)
- [Google Drive Search Query Terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms)
- [Apps with access to your account](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1)
- [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)

  - [Feature Request: Listing and searching for container bound scripts](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761966)
  - [Create an Apps Script Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113)